# Почему при создании Image в сцене его родитель Canvas несоразмерно огромный

Tags: unity3d

Почему при создании Image в сцене его родитель Canvas несоразмерно огромный, он больше игровой локации и тем более изображения, изображение 100х100 а он 1000х400.

Он создается по размерам экрана? Можно ли как то изменить его размеры или это не имеет смысла?

Comment: В Scene View? В самой игре то норм?

Comment: @Suvitruf да в Scene View он меня беспокоит

Answer (score 0):

Canvas не принадлежит конкретному Image. Это холст на котором размещается интерфейс - на нём может быть сколько угодно всего: и картинки и кнопки, и разные переключатели.

Почитайте [документацию Unity о компоненте](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Canvas.html)

Ответ на ваш вопрос описан в документации. Если коротко - это связано с режимом отрисовки данного "Холста". В поле Render Mode установлено "Overlay" - т.е. Canvas будет растягиваться на весь экран а находиться всегда поверх всего остального, что рисуется на экране.